# How to convert a type result into a string in python?

Tags: python-3.x, string, type-conversion

I have a code line

```
emp_id=1 
tp = type(emp_id)
print(tp)
print(type(tp))
strg = str(tp)
print(strg)
print(type(strg))
```

The result is  as below

```
<class 'int'>
<class 'type'>
<class 'int'>
<class 'str'>
```

**What i need is i want to store  in a string.

How to do it? **

Comment: Would you please clarify what is the expected output? This looks correct to me.

Comment: So you want to store a type object in a string

Comment: What i need is i want to store class 'int' only in  the strg with out angular quotes.@Tonystark   yes

Answer (score 5):

The function **`type(x)`** returns the **class** of which the object `x` is an instance. All classes in python have the property **`__name__`** which returns the **actual name** (as a string) of that class.

```
x = 1
tp = type(x).__name__
print(tp)
```

This will print:  `int`

Comment: Excellent i got what i need.@Aziz i need the explanation of what does __ name __ consists and how does it eliminated <class > from the result.If possible pelase explain in laymens terms.

Comment: @GUMMADIVIJAYAKUMAR I added more clarification to the answer.